# C# group a list and then remove odd numbered records from groups

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of items and I am grouping them successfully via ID.

```
        var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(i => i.ID);
```

Then I am trying to go through the groups and if the group has an odd number of items, I want to remove the last item in that group. This is not working.

```
        groupedItems = groupedItems.Select(
                g => {
                    return (g.Count % 2 == 0) ?
                         g :
                         g.RemoveAt(g.Count - 1);                            
                }
            ).ToList();
```

If I can combine the two functions into one that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
var groupedItems =
    items.GroupBy(i => i.ID)
         .Select(g => g.Take(g.Count() / 2 * 2))
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove elements from an `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>`. It is an immutable data structure.

To omit the last item from odd counted groups you can write

```
var groupedItems = from item in items
                   group item by item.ID into byID
                   let odd = byID.Count() % 2 == 0
                   select odd ? byID.SkipLast(1) : byID;
```

If you wish to retain the keys, you can project the results differently

```
var groupedItems = from item in items
                   group item by item.ID into byID
                   let odd = byID.Count() % 2 == 0
                   select (id: byID.Key, values: odd ? byID.SkipLast(1) : byID);
```

And iterate over them like so

```
foreach (var (id, values) in groupedItems) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{id}: {values.ToArray()}");
}
```